There is a Base Clock difference by service in ubuntu 20.04
Currently using Intel Xeon 4216, 6226R CPU in bare metal.
Base clocks of 2.1GHz and 2.9GHz are normal, but only 800MHz and 1200MHz are confirmed as the lowest clocks.
For servers used by other services (Ceph, OpenStack), the Base Clock is checked as low, and only on the K8s server, the Base Clock is checked correctly.
I want to set the Base Clock equally for all of them. It cannot be modified using tuned, cpufreq, cpupower, etc. in the OS.
Is there any part involved in CPU Clock in k8s?
